# Exit does not terminating process

Tags: c

I have a task to create a program, which works like bash. It has interactive mode and kinda *batch file* mode. But the problem is not in that.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80
#define MAX_ARGS 10
#define MAX_PATH 1024

char error_message[30] = "An error has occurred\n";
int exit_cmd = 0;

int parse_args(char *line, char **args, char **output_file) {
    int i = 0;
    char *token, *sep = " \t\n";

    while ((token = strsep(&line, sep)) != NULL) {
        if (*token == '\0') {
            continue; // skip empty tokens
        }

        if (strcmp(token, ">") == 0) {
            // Output redirection
            token = strsep(&line, sep);
            if (token == NULL) {
                write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            *output_file = token;
            continue;
        }

        args[i++] = token;

        if (i == MAX_ARGS) {
            write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    args[i+1] = NULL;

    return i;
}

void set_path(char **args, int num_args, char **path_arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PATH; i++) {
        path_arr[i] = NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < num_args && i - 1 < MAX_PATH; i++) {
        path_arr[i - 1] = (char *)malloc(strlen(args[i]) + 1);
        strcpy(path_arr[i - 1], args[i]);
    }
}

char *get_output_file(char **args) {
    int i = 0;
    while (args[i] != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(args[i], ">") == 0) {
            return args[i + 1];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int batch_mode = 0;
    FILE *batch_file = NULL;
    char *path_arr[MAX_PATH] = { NULL };
    path_arr[0] = "/bin";
    char *output_file = NULL;

    if (argc >= 2) {
        batch_mode = 1;
        batch_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        output_file = get_output_file(argv);
        if (output_file != NULL) {
            FILE *fdb = fopen(output_file, "w");
            if (fdb == NULL) {
                write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
                return 0;
            }
            dup2(fileno(fdb), STDOUT_FILENO);
            dup2(fileno(fdb), STDERR_FILENO);
            fclose(fdb);
        }

        if (batch_file == NULL) {
            write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } else if (argc != 1) {
        write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (!exit_cmd) {
        if (!batch_mode) {
            printf("wish> ");
        }

        char *line = NULL;
        size_t bufsize = 0;
        ssize_t linelen;
        if (batch_mode) {
            linelen = getline(&line, &bufsize, batch_file);
            if (linelen == -1) {
                free(line);
                break;
            }
        } else {
            linelen = getline(&line, &bufsize, stdin);
            if (linelen == -1) {
                free(line);
                break;
            }
        }

        char *args[MAX_ARGS + 1] = { NULL };
        output_file = NULL;
        int num_args = parse_args(line, args, &output_file);

        if (num_args == -1) {
            write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
            continue;
        }

        // printf("line: %s\n", line);
        // printf("exit_cmd: %d\n", exit_cmd);
        // write(STDERR_FILENO, line, strlen(line));
        // write(STDERR_FILENO, args[0], strlen(args[0]));
        // write(STDERR_FILENO, "\n", strlen("\n"));

        if (num_args > 0) {
            if (strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0) {
                if (num_args != 1) {
                    write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
                    continue;
                } else {
                    exit_cmd = 1;
                    free(line);
                    exit(0);
                }
            } else if (strcmp(args[0], "cd") == 0) {
                if (exit_cmd) {
                    free(line);
                    exit(0);
                }

                if (num_args != 2) {
                    write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
                    continue;
                }
                if (chdir(args[1]) != 0) {
                    write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
                }
                free(line);
                continue;
            } else if (strcmp(args[0], "path") == 0) {
                if (exit_cmd) {
                    free(line);
                    exit(0);
                }

                set_path(args, num_args, path_arr);
                free(line);
                continue;
            }

            // Check if output redirection is requested
            if (num_args >= 3 && strcmp(args[num_args - 2], ">") == 0) {
                output_file = args[num_args - 1];
                args[num_args - 2] = NULL;
            }

            if (exit_cmd) {
                free(line);
                exit(0);
            }
            
            pid_t pid = fork();
            if (pid == -1) {
                free(line);
                write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            } else if (pid == 0) {
                FILE *fd = NULL;
                if (output_file != NULL) {
                    fd = fopen(output_file, "w");
                    if (fd == NULL) {
                        free(line);
                        write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
                        return 0;
                    }
                    dup2(fileno(fd), STDOUT_FILENO);
                    dup2(fileno(fd), STDERR_FILENO);
                    fclose(fd);
                }
                if (path_arr[0] == NULL) {
                    printf("%s\n", args[0]);
                    free(line);
                    execv(args[0], args);
                    write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; path_arr[i] != NULL; i++) {
                        char *path = (char *)malloc(strlen(path_arr[i]) + strlen(args[0]) + 2);
                        strcpy(path, path_arr[i]);
                        strcat(path, "/");
                        strcat(path, args[0]);
                        execv(path, args);
                        write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                wait(NULL);
            }
        }
    }

    if (batch_mode) {
        fclose(batch_file);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So the problem is visible when I'm trying to execute some program, like **ls**:

```bash
wish> path tests
wish> p1.sh
test1  test2  test3  test4
wish> path
wish> p1.sh
p1.sh
An error has occurred
wish> ls
ls
An error has occurred
wish> exit
wish> exit
wish> exit
```

I think, that when I call `exit(0);` program exiting from child process, but I don't know how to make it exiting from parent process

P.S. I know, that my program has many *bad code*)

Comment: Reduce your code to a [mre]. Remove all parts not needed for demonstrating the problem. Document the code; put in comments explaining what things do and why they are designed the way they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears to be what you do when `execv` fails in the child process, or rather what you do not do. Since the process is never replaced, your code continues executing as if it was the parent process. You need to better handling for when `execv` fails.

I've cut your code sample down to something that should help you see the problem.

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ...
    while (!exit_cmd) {
        // do all the normal parent process stuff
        ...

        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            free(line);
            write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            // now in child process
            execv(args[0], args);
            // execv replaces the current process and so any code shouldn't
            // be executed if it succeeded.
            write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));
            // maybe add the following?
            // exit(SOME_ERROR_STATUS);
        } else {
            // if parent process, then wait for child process to terminate
            wait(NULL);
        }
    } // End of while loop block -- loop back to the start
      // However, if execv failed, then the child process will still be
      // executing in this loop. But, it has nothing to indicate then it 
      // should not be executing this code. Thus, the child process will start 
      // executing the code that the parent was meant to execute. You need to 
      // properly terminate the child process if execv fails.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues in the code:

- in `parse_args`, you set a `NULL` terminator at `args[i+1]`. You should instead set it at `args[i]`.
- the error messages should be more explicit. Why not use `fprintf` for these?
- all tests on `exit_cmd` in `main` are useless since you call `exit()` explicitly when the `args[0]` matches the `"exit"` command.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAX_ARGS 32
#define MAX_PATH 32

int parse_args(char *line, char **args, char **input_file, char **output_file) {
    int i = 0;
    char *token;
    const char *sep = " \t\n";

    while ((token = strsep(&line, sep)) != NULL) {
        if (*token == '\0') {
            // skip empty tokens
            continue;
        }
        if (*token == '#') {
            // ignore comments
            break;
        }
        if (*token == '>') { // Output redirection
            token++;
            while (*token == '\0') {
                token = strsep(&line, sep);
                if (token == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "missing output filename\n");
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            *output_file = token;
            continue;
        }
        if (*token == '<') { // Input redirection
            token++;
            while (*token == '\0') {
                token = strsep(&line, sep);
                if (token == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "missing input filename\n");
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            *input_file = token;
            continue;
        }
        args[i++] = token;

        if (i == MAX_ARGS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "too many arguments\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    args[i] = NULL;
    return i;
}

void init_path(char **path_arr) {
    char *path = getenv("PATH");
    size_t i, len;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_PATH; i++) {
        path += strspn(path, ":%");
        if (*path == '\0')
            break;
        len = strcspn(path, ":%");
        path_arr[i] = strndup(path, len);
        path += len;
    }
    path_arr[i] = NULL;
}

void set_path(char **args, int num_args, char **path_arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PATH; i++) {
        free(path_arr[i]);
        if (i < num_args)
            path_arr[i] = strdup(args[i]);
        else
            path_arr[i] = NULL;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *path_arr[MAX_PATH + 1];
    FILE *input = stdin;
    int batch_mode = 0;

    /* populate from PATH variable */
    init_path(path_arr);

    if (argc >= 2) {
        batch_mode = 1;
        input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (input == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot open command file %s: %s\n",
                    argv[1], strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t line_size = 0;
    int status = 0;

    for (;;) {
        if (!batch_mode) {
            printf("wish> ");
        }

        if (getline(&line, &line_size, input) < 0)
            break;

        char *args[MAX_ARGS + 1];
        char *input_file = NULL;
        char *output_file = NULL;
        int num_args = parse_args(line, args, &input_file, &output_file);

        if (num_args <= 0)
            continue;

        if (strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0) {
            if (num_args > 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "wish: exit: too many arguments\n");
                continue;
            }
            if (num_args == 2) {
                char *endp;
                status = strtol(args[1], &endp, 10);
                if (endp == args[1]) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "wish: exit: numeric argument required\n");
                    status = 1;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            break;
        } else if (strcmp(args[0], "cd") == 0) {
            char *directory;
            status = 0;
            if (num_args == 1) {
                directory = getenv("HOME");
            } else
            if (num_args == 2) {
                directory = args[1];
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "usage: cd directory\n");
                status = 1;
                continue;
            }
            if (chdir(directory) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "cd: cannot change directory to %s: %s\n",
                        directory, strerror(errno));
                status = 1;
            }
            continue;
        } else if (strcmp(args[0], "path") == 0) {
            status = 0;
            set_path(args + 1, num_args - 1, path_arr);
            continue;
        }

        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "wish: cannot fork: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            status = 1;
            continue;
        }
        if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
            if (input_file) {
                int hd = open(input_file, O_RDONLY);
                if (hd < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "wish: cannot open input file %s: %s\n", input_file, strerror(errno));
                    return 1;
                }
                dup2(hd, STDIN_FILENO);
                close(hd);
            }
            if (output_file) {
                int hd = open(output_file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
                if (hd < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "wish: cannot open output file %s: %s\n", output_file, strerror(errno));
                    return 1;
                }
                dup2(hd, STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(hd);
            }
            if (path_arr[0] == NULL) {
                if (!access(args[0], X_OK)) {
                    execv(args[0], args);
                    fprintf(stderr, "wish: cannot exec process %s: %s\n", args[0], strerror(errno));
                    return 1;
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; path_arr[i] != NULL; i++) {
                    char *path = malloc(strlen(path_arr[i]) + strlen(args[0]) + 2);
                    strcpy(path, path_arr[i]);
                    strcat(path, "/");
                    strcat(path, args[0]);
                    if (!access(path, X_OK)) {
                        execv(path, args);
                        fprintf(stderr, "wish: cannot exec process %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
                        return 1;
                    }
                    free(path);
                }
            }
            fprintf(stderr, "wish: no executable file %s\n", args[0]);
            return 1;
        } else {
            /* parent process: get status */
            wait(&status);
        }
    }

    free(line);

    if (batch_mode) {
        fclose(input);
    }
    return status;
}
```